# C++ error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'char *' to 'int'

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am developing an MFC application in vc++ 6.0. I created one int variable (`m_iEdit1`) to the EditBox1 and one CString variable (`m_strEdit2`) to the EditBox2. I wanted to give the condition that two editbox must not be empty.

```
if(m_iEdit1==" ")
    return;

if(m_strEdit2==" ")
   return;
```

But the first condition will not work here I will get the error:

```
error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'char *' to 'int'
```

How to check an int Variable of EditBox is Empty or not?

Comment: Is this an MFC app? Is it a .NET app?

Comment: no it is vc++ 6.0 not in .net

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [UpdateData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww(VS.80).aspx) method.
The m_ variables will not get the data from the controls unless you *say* it.

```
UpdateData(TRUE) // the m_ variables will be updated from the controls
UpdateData(FALSE) // the controls will be updated from m_ variables
```

You want m_iEdit1 to be integer but since you need to check if the EditBox1 is empty change m_iEdit1 to CString. Then you can use

```
atoi(m_iEdit1)
```

to get the integer value.

Now that both m_iEdit1 and m_strEdit2 are CStrings you can use the code

```
if ( m_iEdit1.IsEmpty() ) return;
if ( m_strEdit2.IsEmpty() ) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the actual EditBox variable (did you call it EditBox1?) to see if the value is empty.

You should also consider other checks as well to ensure no one is trying to assign non numerical values to your integer value.

Comment: yes it is actual EditBox1 Variable.How to see the value is empty can u give the example. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GetLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7775836w(VS.71).aspx) method to get the string from the edit control. Then you can use IsEmpty (assuming you passed a CString) to check whether it is empty.

Comment: because i want intger values not CString

Comment: First get the value to a CString. Then you can use functions like _ttoi to convert it to integer.